# NSView won't draw through bezierpath

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbezierpath

Dear fellow Cocoa programmers,

**What I'd like to accomplish:**

I have a checkbox, a popUpButton(which is hidden) and a NSView on my canvas. 
If myCheckbox is checked -> show the popUpButton and draw a line through bezierPath on the NSView.
if myCheckbox is UNchecked -> Hide the popUpButton again and "undraw" the path

**The code:**

```
- (IBAction)isChecked:(id)sender {
  //if myChekcbox is checked, show the pop up button
  if ([sender state]==NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"Checked");
    [myPopUp setHidden:NO];
  }
  else
  {
    //if the checkbox is unchecked, hide the popupbutton
    [myPopUp setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"Unchecked");

  }
  //reload my drawrect method (reload the view)
  [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
  //if the checkedbutton is checked, draw the line
  if ([myCheckbox state]==NSOnState)
  {
    NSBezierPath *myPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [myPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(10, 20)];
    [myPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(50, 20)];
    [myPath setLineWidth:2];
    [myPath stroke];
  }

}
```

**The problem:**

if checked state = NSOnState the popUpButton is visible but the line just won't draw and I wonder why... I personally think it's a connection(s) problem.

I uploaded the project file (it's rather small-35kb) here:[Drawing.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1n4pqv2jh9adji1/Drawing.zip)

**Globally:**
I've read the NSView documentation and it's saying there is only one way to draw to a view and it's through the drawRect method. Is this actually true? Also is this a descent way to draw to a view? (if function in the view and setNeedsDisplay:YES in the method)

thanks in advance, 
Ben

Comment: Found out the problem: it was a connection problem and the 
self setNeedsDisplay: YES 
should be: myView setNeedsDisplay:YES

Quite silly! thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get an `NSColor` instance and then call [`setStroke`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColor/setStroke) on it to set a current stroke color. It does not know which color to use to stroke the path at the start of `drawRect:`, so you have to tell it.

Comment: Jesper, The code runs but it won't do 'the trick' héhé. I just changed the Drawing.zip to the correct link, excuse me for that.

Comment: Which is weird, since the line draws without the IF-statement.